# Create many 1MB files with random content with filenames reading from text file

Tags: command-line

Need help in creating bulk files with varying size of less than 1MB, with random data.

My file with filenames looks like this:

```
6d3a3f2e-ed34-11ea-adc1-0242ac120002||aaa
6d3a4000-ed34-11ea-adc1-0242ac120002||aaa
6d3a428a-ed34-11ea-adc1-0242ac120002||aaa
```

---

Output: Multiple files with the above mentioned filenames with varying size less than 1 MB.

Hoping to get a single line execution statement

Comment: Are pipe symbol mandatory ?

Comment: Yes, that's a requirement in the filename for upload.

Answer (score 3):

untested:

```bsh
while IFS= read -r filename; do
  dd if=/dev/random of="$filename" bs=1MB count=1
done < file_with_filenames
```

That reads 1 block of 1MB bytes from input file /dev/random and copies to the output file $filename.

That's not files of varying sizes: each one will be 1,000,000 bytes. But you could do something like

```bsh
dd bs=$((1000000 - RANDOM)) if=...
```